# Can't access to other functions inside a callback function

Tags: javascript

I have problem accessing other functions inside a ajax post callback function.

take a look at this code:

```
function HelloWorld(){
    var x = 'Hello';
    return x;
}

console.log( HelloWorld() ); // this works fine.

$('#newPost').click( function(){

    $.post('url', { somedata }, function( data ){
        console.log( HelloWorld() );
        // this does not work.
        // Error: functions not defined.
    });

});
```

How can I have access to other functions?

Comment: Can you write a more complete example (see http://sscce.org) ?

Comment: thanks, but I think it's a complete question. scope problem is here. not ajax problem.

Comment: The problem isn't in the code you show.

Comment: other functions are from another js file.

Comment: Are they defined in a closure ? Please pay attention to the link I gave : you must provide code enabling the reproduction of the problem.

Comment: If `somedata` is an object, wrapping it in `{}` could be the problem.

Comment: they are inside another file which starts with a jquery ready. sorry I am new to javascript

Comment: with this update, yes ajax post is within a click closure. any help?

Comment: Your code fails to reproduce the problem you describe, but instead runs perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/bwH64/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `HelloWorld` is in `jQuery.ready` scope, then you will not have access to it, it is local for that scope.

If you want to make `HelloWorld` global, then you should use window or this:

```
window.HelloWorld = function(){
  var x = 'Hello';
  return x;
}
```

Then it will be accessible in any another scope.